# Algebraic rigidity in the automorphism group of the Cantor set

Tags: gr.group-theory, gt.geometric-topology, geometric-group-theory, topological-groups

Let C be a Cantor set (middle third). Now we know that C is a totally disconnected compact topological space with the natural topology (i.e., $C=\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$). Let **G:=Homeo(C)** be the set of all homeomorphisms of the Cantor space C. Then G is a topological group with the usual compact-open topology. We know (by an old result of Anderson) that G is a simple group. Therefore $G\cong Inn(G)$. My question is: what is the full automorphism group (denoted by $Aut(G)$) of G? Is it possible to prove that for every automorphism $\phi\in Aut(G)$ there exists $f\in G$ such that $\phi(g)=fgf^{-1}$ for all $g\in G$?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: It's reduced to inner automorphism (i.e., Out=1). This follows from very general results of Rubin in the 80's but probably was proved earlier. I assume that you meant automorphism as topological group, but this is even true for arbitrary group automorphisms.

Comment: PS: Rubin showed that for many "rich enough" subgroups $H$ of $\mathrm{Homeo}(C)$, its automorphism group is equal to its normalizer in $\mathrm{Homeo}(C)$.

Comment: @YCor: Thank you very much for your answer. Yes you are right if all the abstract automorphisms are inner, then they are continuous as well. Is it possible for you to share the title of this paper.

Comment: What I said is not this trivial fact. I said that not only all bi-continuous automorphism are inner, but all automorphisms are inner. There exist topological groups for which the "topological" Out is trivial while the "abstract" Out isn't.

Comment: The Rubin reference is "On the reconstruction of topological spaces from their groups oh homeomorphisms" by M. Rubin, Trans. AMS 312 no 2, 487-538 1989. [Link at AMS site](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1989-312-02/S0002-9947-1989-0988881-4/) [DOI](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9947-1989-0988881-4)

Comment: @YCor: Thank you very much for the link. I see what you are saying.